# IMFStreamSink::ProcessSample "E_NOINTERFACE No such interface supported"

Tags: c++, windows, video, video-processing, ms-media-foundation

I'm trying to do a quick and dirty POC. I have a raw H264 file (Not mp4, no container whatsoever, just the raw H264 wrapped in NALU's) to simulate the device my application will ultimately be reading from.

I've been following the Media Foundation Docs. I'm simply reading the H264 file in chunks of 1024 bits using a standard fstream. This just simulated the data getting streamed. From there I'm manually creating IMFSamples and sending them to the decoder. It takes a couple passes to get enough data to fill a frame, but eventually it successfully decodes.

Once I try to pass that off to a IMFStreamSink that I got from the EVR, I get the HRESULT "E_NOINTERFACE No such interface supported" I know that the decompressed sample has data in it. I've used the debugger to confirm. I'm really confused why I'm getting this error as there is no additional data to go along with it.

Here is my code Isolated to the run loop:

```
while (true) {
            // My Loop Stuff

            IMFMediaBuffer* inputBuffer = CreateMediaBuffer(1024);
            IMFSample* compressedSample = CreateMediaSample(inputBuffer);

            if (compressedSample == NULL) {
                return 1;
            }

            BYTE* tempBuff;
            DWORD tempMaxLength = 0;
            DWORD tempCurrentLength = 0;

            hr = inputBuffer->Lock(
                &tempBuff,
                &tempMaxLength,
                &tempCurrentLength
            );

            if (FAILED(hr)) {
                std::cout << "Failed to lock buffer" << std::endl;
                return 1;
            }

            inputTestFile.read((char*)tempBuff, tempMaxLength - tempCurrentLength);

            hr = inputBuffer->SetCurrentLength(tempMaxLength - tempCurrentLength);

            if (FAILED(hr)) {
                std::cout << "Failed to set the lenght of the buffer" << std::endl;
                return 1;
            }

            hr = inputBuffer->Unlock();

            if (FAILED(hr)) {
                std::cout << "FAILED to unlock buffer!" << std::endl;
                return 1;
            }

            hr = pDecoder->ProcessInput(0, compressedSample, 0);

            if (FAILED(hr)) {
                std::cout << "Failed sending compressedSample to decoder" << std::endl;

                IMFMediaBuffer* outputBuffer = CreateMediaBuffer(streamInfo.cbSize);
                IMFSample* decompressedSample = CreateMediaSample(outputBuffer);

                _MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER outBuff = {};
                outBuff.dwStreamID = 0;
                outBuff.pSample = decompressedSample;

                _MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER outBuffs[] = { outBuff };
                DWORD outStatus = 0;

                hr = pDecoder->ProcessOutput(0, 1, outBuffs, &outStatus);

                if (FAILED(hr)) {
                    std::cout << "FAILED TO PROCESS OUTPUT" << std::endl;
                    continue;
                    //return 1;
                }
                else {
                    std::cout << "Successfully decoded data!!!" << std::endl;

                    IMFMediaEvent* mediaEvent = NULL;

                    ssink->GetEvent(0, &mediaEvent);

                    if (mediaEvent == NULL) {
                        // Nothing to do.. Wait for a request for more 
                        continue;
                    }

                    hr = ssink->ProcessSample(decompressedSample);

                    if (FAILED(hr)) {
                        std::cout << "Failed to process sample to sink" << std::endl;
                        continue;
                    }

                }
            }
            // END My Loop Stuff
        }
```

Here is my complete code: (Search for "My Stuff" and "My Loop Stuff" to get around all the boilerplate)

```
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_H264RENDERINGWINDOW, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_H264RENDERINGWINDOW));

    MSG msg;

    // My Stuff


    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    UINT32 count = 0;

    hr = MFStartup(MF_VERSION);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return 1;
    }

    IMFActivate** ppActivate = NULL;    // Array of activation objects.
    IMFTransform* pDecoder = NULL;      // Pointer to the decoder.

    // Match WMV3 video.
    MFT_REGISTER_TYPE_INFO info = { MFMediaType_Video, MFVideoFormat_H264 };

    UINT32 unFlags = MFT_ENUM_FLAG_SYNCMFT |
        MFT_ENUM_FLAG_LOCALMFT |
        MFT_ENUM_FLAG_SORTANDFILTER;

    hr = MFTEnumEx(
        MFT_CATEGORY_VIDEO_DECODER,
        unFlags,
        &info,      // Input type
        NULL,       // Output type
        &ppActivate,
        &count
    );


    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && count == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "NOT SUCCESS!!!!" << std::endl;
        //hr = MF_E_TOPO_CODEC_NOT_FOUND;
        return 1;
    }

    // Create the first decoder in the list.

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "SUCCESS AGAIN!!!" << std::endl;
        hr = ppActivate[0]->ActivateObject(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pDecoder));
    }

    DWORD pcInputStreamsNum = 0;
    DWORD pcOutputStreamsNum = 0;

    hr = pDecoder->GetStreamCount(
        &pcInputStreamsNum,
        &pcOutputStreamsNum
    );

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cout << "Unable to get stream count" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Available Input Streams: " << pcInputStreamsNum << " Available Output Streams: " << pcOutputStreamsNum << std::endl;

    IMFMediaType* pInMediaType = NULL;

    hr = MFCreateMediaType(
        &pInMediaType
    );

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cout << "Unable to create Input Media Type" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    hr = pDecoder->GetInputAvailableType(
        0,
        0,
        &pInMediaType
    );

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cout << "Unable to get Input Media Type for Decoder" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    hr = pDecoder->SetInputType(
        0,
        pInMediaType,
        0
    );

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cout << "Unable to set Media Type for Decoder" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    IMFMediaType* pOutMediaType = NULL;

    hr = MFCreateMediaType(
        &pOutMediaType
    );

    hr = pDecoder->GetOutputAvailableType(0, 0, &pOutMediaType);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cout << "Unable to get output type" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    GUID v;

    hr = pOutMediaType->GetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, &v);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cout << "Unable to get output media sub-type" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    hr = pDecoder->SetOutputType(0, pOutMediaType, 0);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cout << "Failed setting output type" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    hr = pDecoder->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_BEGIN_STREAMING, NULL);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to send begin streaming message" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Successfully Initialized the Decoder..." << std::endl;

    std::ifstream inputTestFile = std::ifstream("c:\\open\\fbsource\\arvr\\apps\\MagicIsle\\magic-capture.h264", std::ios::binary);

    if (!inputTestFile.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "unable to open test input file, did run with --capture previously?"
            << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    MFT_INPUT_STREAM_INFO inStreamInfo{};

    hr = pDecoder->GetInputStreamInfo(
        0,
        &inStreamInfo
    );

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to get the stream info" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Stream Info: ";

    if (inStreamInfo.dwFlags == MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_CAN_PROVIDE_SAMPLES) {
        std::cout << "MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_CAN_PROVIDE_SAMPLES" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (inStreamInfo.dwFlags == MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_CAN_PROVIDE_SAMPLES) {
        std::cout << "MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_PROVIDES_SAMPLES" << std::endl;
    }


    MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_INFO streamInfo{};

    hr = pDecoder->GetOutputStreamInfo(
        0,
        &streamInfo
    );

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to get the stream info" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Stream Info: ";

    if (streamInfo.dwFlags == MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_CAN_PROVIDE_SAMPLES) {
        std::cout << "MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_CAN_PROVIDE_SAMPLES" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (streamInfo.dwFlags == MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_CAN_PROVIDE_SAMPLES) {
        std::cout << "MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_PROVIDES_SAMPLES" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "NEITHER" << std::endl;
    }

    IMFPresentationClock* clock = NULL;

    hr = MFCreatePresentationClock(&clock);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
       return 1;
    }

    IMFPresentationTimeSource* timeSource = NULL;

    hr = MFCreateSystemTimeSource(&timeSource);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return 1;
    }

    hr = clock->SetTimeSource(timeSource);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return 1;
    }

    hr = clock->Start(0);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return 1;
    }

    hr = pRenderer->SetPresentationClock(clock);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return 1;
    }

    DWORD rendererCharacteristics = 0;

    hr = pRenderer->GetCharacteristics(&rendererCharacteristics);

    if ((rendererCharacteristics & MEDIASINK_CANNOT_MATCH_CLOCK) == MEDIASINK_CANNOT_MATCH_CLOCK) {
        std::cout << "Cannot Match Clock" << std::endl;
    }

    if ((rendererCharacteristics & MEDIASINK_RATELESS) == MEDIASINK_RATELESS) {
        std::cout << "Rateless" << std::endl;
    }

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return 1;
    }

    IMFStreamSink* ssink = NULL;

    hr = pRenderer->GetStreamSinkById(0, &ssink);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return 1;
    }

    IMFMediaTypeHandler* ssinkMediaTypeHandler = NULL;

    hr = ssink->GetMediaTypeHandler(&ssinkMediaTypeHandler);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return 1;
    }

    hr = ssinkMediaTypeHandler->SetCurrentMediaType(pOutMediaType);

    // End My Stuff

    auto f = [&] {

        while (true) {
            // My Loop Stuff

            IMFMediaBuffer* inputBuffer = CreateMediaBuffer(1024);
            IMFSample* compressedSample = CreateMediaSample(inputBuffer);

            if (compressedSample == NULL) {
                return 1;
            }

            BYTE* tempBuff;
            DWORD tempMaxLength = 0;
            DWORD tempCurrentLength = 0;

            hr = inputBuffer->Lock(
                &tempBuff,
                &tempMaxLength,
                &tempCurrentLength
            );

            if (FAILED(hr)) {
                std::cout << "Failed to lock buffer" << std::endl;
                return 1;
            }

            inputTestFile.read((char*)tempBuff, tempMaxLength - tempCurrentLength);

            hr = inputBuffer->SetCurrentLength(tempMaxLength - tempCurrentLength);

            if (FAILED(hr)) {
                std::cout << "Failed to set the lenght of the buffer" << std::endl;
                return 1;
            }

            hr = inputBuffer->Unlock();

            if (FAILED(hr)) {
                std::cout << "FAILED to unlock buffer!" << std::endl;
                return 1;
            }

            hr = pDecoder->ProcessInput(0, compressedSample, 0);

            if (FAILED(hr)) {
                std::cout << "Failed sending compressedSample to decoder" << std::endl;

                IMFMediaBuffer* outputBuffer = CreateMediaBuffer(streamInfo.cbSize);
                IMFSample* decompressedSample = CreateMediaSample(outputBuffer);

                _MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER outBuff = {};
                outBuff.dwStreamID = 0;
                outBuff.pSample = decompressedSample;

                _MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER outBuffs[] = { outBuff };
                DWORD outStatus = 0;

                hr = pDecoder->ProcessOutput(0, 1, outBuffs, &outStatus);

                if (FAILED(hr)) {
                    std::cout << "FAILED TO PROCESS OUTPUT" << std::endl;
                    continue;
                    //return 1;
                }
                else {
                    std::cout << "Successfully decoded data!!!" << std::endl;

                    IMFMediaEvent* mediaEvent = NULL;

                    ssink->GetEvent(0, &mediaEvent);

                    if (mediaEvent == NULL) {
                        // Nothing to do.. Wait for a request for more 
                        continue;
                    }

                    hr = ssink->ProcessSample(decompressedSample);

                    if (FAILED(hr)) {
                        std::cout << "Failed to process sample to sink" << std::endl;
                        continue;
                    }

                }
            }
            // END My Loop Stuff
        }
    };

    std::thread t(f);

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        
    }

    t.join();

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Once I try to pass that off to a IMFStreamSink that I got from the EVR, I get the HRESULT "E_NOINTERFACE No such interface supported" I know that the decompressed sample has data in it. I've used the debugger to confirm. I'm really confused why I'm getting this error as there is no additional data to go along with it.

You are sending a sample to the sink when it's in wrong state.

Per [Media Sinks >> Data Flow #3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/media-sinks#data-flow), you are responsible to work with events and asynchronous model of Media Foundation sinks. Specifically, media sink requests sample first and only then you can send it.

Normally Media Session or other Media Foundation APIs handle this, but in your case it's your responsibility.

Comment: I've updated my code, but still getting the same error:
```
                    if (met == MEStreamSinkRequestSample) {
                        hr = ssink->ProcessSample(decompressedSample);

                    }
                    else {
                        std::cout << "Got event but wasn't request sample" << std::endl;
                    }
```

Comment: Your edit does not repeat the data flow sinks have in their intended environment, the one documented at linked MSDN webpage.

Comment: What am I missing? The preroll? If so, isn't that optional? I'm specifically waiting for the "MEStreamSinkRequestSample" event to send the sample. Is there another one I need to listen for?

Comment: I believe the EVR sink does not implement the full compliance, and it's technically possible to cut things short the way you try to do it, but I would not expect it to work without [state notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/media-sinks#state-changes) at the very least. Also what you refer to as "complete code" is not complete because it's can't be built and executed.

Comment: Ahh yeah, I guess "Complete Code" I mean, Main Function. Shouldn't EVR be fully compatible with MFT? Going to see if that helps. Will report back here if not.
Would you like me to provide the entire 900 lines of code? I unfortunately won't be able to give you the raw h264 test file.

Comment: One more thing that is odd. I'm trying to implement the preroll, so I can say I've followed the docs you linked "exactly". The EVR does return MEDIASINK_CAN_PREROLL when I ask for characteristics, however when I query for the preroll interface, I still get "E_NOINTERFACE"
```
void* voidPreRoll = NULL;

        hr = pDecoder->QueryInterface(IID_IMFMediaSinkPreroll, &voidPreRoll);

        IMFMediaSinkPreroll* preRoll = (IMFMediaSinkPreroll*)voidPreRoll;
```

Comment: Generally speaking what you are doing does not make a lot of sense to me. I would drop the EVR completely and just visualize the decoded video frames using D3D11 swapchain. I think in the end this will be easier than using EVR as a sink in  your POC attempt.

Comment: Ok, going to try that! I thought EVR would be the easiest way to do it. Going to try swap chain! Thanks Roman! I will go and upvote your answer, but need you to update it first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251671/discussion-between-luckybroman5-and-roman-r).

Comment: Referring to completeness of code, it's up to you what you want to include in your question. Trying to get external help you might want to offer someone else the code one could build and run, because it helps troubleshooting. This is what complete code is.